# Continuously run a DAG after 2 minutes of completion of the previous run in Airflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs

I want to know if we can schedule a DAG to run continuously after 2 minutes of completion of the same DAG in Airflow.

**Edit:**

My DAG should run in such a way that every time it completes its run, it has to wait for 2 minutes and start running again. I don't want to schedule my DAG to run for every 2 minutes instead it should continuously run right after 2 minutes of completion of the same DAG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could schedule your dag at an arbitrary time in a day and use the [`TriggerDagRunOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun/index.html#airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun.TriggerDagRunOperator) to trigger itself again. To wait for 2 minutes before triggering itself, you could simply introduce a sleep task.

DAG:

Task 1 >> Task 2 >> Task 3 `BashOperator(bash_command="sleep 120")` >> Task 4 `TriggerDagRunOperator(trigger_dag_id="this-dag-id")`

Comment: Yes I did exactly the same. That worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can schedule DAG to run every 2 Minutes.

Set `schedule_interval='*/2 * * * *'`

Schedule_interval accepts a CRON expression:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression

[Structuring dag](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/writing-dags#structure)

If you want to rerun  continuously after 2 mins try configuring  [TriggerDagRunOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun/index.html#module-airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun)

Comment: No, let me make the question more clear. My DAG should run in such a way that every time it completes its run, it has to wait for 2 minutes and start running again. I dont want to schedule my DAG to run for every 2 minutes instead it should continuously run right after 2 minutes of completion of the same DAG

Comment: ok. Then try using TriggerDagRunOperator to rerun the dag. [LINK](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun/index.html#module-airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun)

Comment: I want to know how the schedule interval looks for such scenario